# Recorrer un texto dividiéndolo cada 15 posiciones con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, substring

Tengo un texto contando los espacios

```
let texto = "La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta";
let ancho = 15;
let contador = 0

let cortado= texto.substring(contador,ancho)
console.log(cortado)
cortado1= texto.substring(ancho,ancho*2)
console.log(cortado1)
cortado2= texto.substring(ancho*2,ancho*3)
console.log(cortado2)
cortado3= texto.substring(ancho*3,ancho*4)
console.log(cortado3)
cortado4= texto.substring(ancho*4,ancho*5)
console.log(cortado4)
```

Existe otra manera de hacerlo y que sea mas dinámico sin repetir tanto. el resultado debería ser:

```
La niña paseaba
 a su perro. Ve
stia un traje a
zul y chupaba u
na paleta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como punto de partida:

```js
...

cortado3 = texto.substring(ancho * 3, ancho * 4)
console.log(cortado3)
cortado4 = texto.substring(ancho * 4, ancho * 5)
console.log(cortado4)
```

Y citando la siguiente inquietud, cito:

> ¿Existe otra manera de hacerlo y que sea más dinámico sin repetir tanto?

Efectivamente si. De hecho, con los pasos manuales que has publicados ya has hecho parte del trabajo. Solo que esta vez, lo vamos a automatizar.

Se tiene un texto:

```js
let texto = "La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta";
```

De la que se desea extraer 15 caracteres en cada **iteración (pasos)**, por lo que, para conocer cuántas veces necesitamos iterar (pasos) debemos obtenerla dividiendo la longitud de la cadena de caracteres por la cantidad de caracteres a extraer, es decir:

```js
let pasos = Math.ceil(texto.length / caracteres)
```

Por otra parte, la razón por la que se utiliza **`Math.ceil()`** es para redondear siempre por exceso (hacia arriba) si la división de la longitud de la cadena entre cantidad de caracteres a extraer es inexacta. De ser exacta la división no hay nada que reondear.

Luego de conocer cuántas iteraciones (pasos) se requieren podemos armar nuestro bucle para recorrer nuestra cadena y extraer las partes que nos interesa:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < pasos; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Y dentro de nuestro bucle definiremos dos variables **`desde`** y **`hasta`**:

```js
let desde = caracteres * i,
    hasta = caracteres * (i + 1);
```

De manera que podamos utilizarla de la siguiente forma:

```js
console.log(texto.substring(desde, hasta));
```

O colocándola dentro de un array:

```js
array.push(texto.substring(desde, hasta));
```

### Visualicémosla en una Demo:

Ya que tenemos claro los pasos que debemos seguir, haremos dos **Demos**, una en la que se muestra el resultado en cada iteración y la otra en un array.

**Ejemplo 1:**

```js
let texto = "La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta";

let caracteres = 15,
  pasos = Math.ceil( texto.length / caracteres );

for ( let i = 0; i < pasos; i++ ) {
  let desde = caracteres * i,
    hasta = caracteres * (i + 1);

  console.log( texto.substring( desde, hasta ) );
}
```

**Ejemplo 2:**

```js
let texto = "La niña paseaba a su perro. Vestía un traje azul y chupaba una paleta";

let array = [],
  caracteres = 15,
  pasos = Math.ceil( texto.length / caracteres );

for ( let i = 0; i < pasos; i++ ) {
  let desde = caracteres * i,
    hasta = caracteres * (i + 1);

  array.push( texto.substring( desde, hasta ) );
}

console.log( array );
```